# disconnect node and return it

Tags: c++, class

i have following fragment of code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class data
{
public:
    long ddata;
    data(long dd)
    {
        ddata=dd;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<ddata<<"  ";
    }




};
class Node
{
     const  int order=4;
    int numitems;
    Node *parent;
    Node *childarray[order];
    data *item[order-1];
public:
    void connect(int childnum,Node *child)
    {
        childarray[childnum]=child;
        if(child!=NULL)
            child->parent=this;


    }
    //disconetc from this node,return it;

    Node *disconnectchild(int childnum)
    {
        Node *tempnode=childarray[childnum];
        childarray[childnum]=NULL;


    }
     return  (tempnode);

}
```

but at return tempnode it  colors this line by red line and says error:expected declaration,please help me to clarify what is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is outside the function definition.